# How to make RoR database query with includes/order work in PostgreSQL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

The following sorting of my Conversation records by the latest ChatMessage works in SQLite, however, not in PostgreSQL. How can I get it to work there?

```
Conversation.includes(:chat_messages).order("chat_messages.created_at DESC")

class Conversation
   has_many :chat_messages
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `references(:chat_messages)`. This will force ActiveRecord to select result by one query:

```
Conversation.
  includes(:chat_messages).references(:chat_messages).
  order("chat_messages.created_at DESC")
```

Read details in [documentation](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/references).